# How to perform batchupdate to delete cell in collectionview swift 5?

Tags: swift, uicollectionview

I am trying to delete item in collectionview using batchupdate in swift 5. but using my code items are not getting deleted. Bellow is my code

```
@IBAction func deleteButtonTapped(sender: UIButton)  -> Void {

        let indexPath = IndexPath(row: sender.tag, section: 0)
        let cell = self.collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath)!
        let itemIndex = self.collectionView.indexPath(for: cell)!.item
        showAlert(title: "Movie - \(searchArray[itemIndex].title) - Deleted", message: "")

        self.collectionView.performBatchUpdates({
            collectionView.deleteItems(at: [(NSIndexPath(item: itemIndex, section: 0) as IndexPath)])
        }, completion: nil)

        //self.collectionView.reloadData()
    }
```

I am doing anything wrong? Do we need to reload collectionview? Please suggest better way.

Thank You

Answer (score 0):

You don't need `performBatchUpdates` – it's only for multiple simultaneous updates – and you don't need to get the cell for the index path and then (again) the index path – which you already know – from the cell.

But you have to remove the item from the data source array

```
@IBAction func deleteButtonTapped(sender: UIButton)  -> Void {

    let indexPath = IndexPath(row: sender.tag, section: 0)
    dataSourceArray.remove(at: indexPath.item)
    showAlert(title: "Movie - \(searchArray[itemIndex].title) - Deleted", message: "")
    collectionView.deleteItems(at: [indexPath])
}
```

Replace `dataSourceArray` with the real name